# Spring advantages over current Java EE

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

It's a short question without a trivial answer. The Java EE Framework does not evolve so fast, but it includes more and more features, some of them taken directly from other open source projects like spring and hibernate. Can you list some of the reasons why you still use spring instead of just relying on the standard Java EE features, and maybe comment each reason with a few words?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go through sites below to know more :

[spring forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?134350-Why-using-Spring-instead-of-JEE6)

[spring-3-0-vs-java-ee-6-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822812/spring-3-0-vs-java-ee-6-0)

[Spring vs Java EE](http://java.dzone.com/articles/thibaultdelor)

[Why Java EE Lost and Spring Won](http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-java-ee-lost-and-spring)