# Spring framework goals explanation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I started to learn a Spring Faramework I focused my attention on specific details but not on clue and global concepts. Actually I can't grasp some of Spring framework goals.

May be this question too wide, but I don't see any sense to divide it into few separate questions. I don't expect that you answer all my question, but at least one of them.

***Spring framework goals:***

1. Make J2EE easier to use
2. Address end-to-end requirements rather than one tier
3. Eliminate need for middle tier “glue”
4. Provide the best Inversion of Control solution
5. Provide a pure Java AOP implementation, focused on solving common problems in J2EE
6. Fully portable across application servers
7. “Non-invasive” framework
8. Facilitate unit testing
9. Facilitate OO best practice
10. Provide a good alternative to EJB for many applications
11. Enhance productivity compared to “traditional” J2EE approaches

***Questions:***

1). Easier to use? By mean of what? And comparing with whom? It seems for me that comparing with pure J2EE each framework provide ease of use. Please more details and examples.

2). Don't understand this point. What is end-to-end requirements?

3). Don't understand this point.

6). Does it mean that another Spring alternatives isn't portable via app servers? Isn't EJB portable?

9). Isn't it the same as 4th point.

11). Please some examples of that non-productive J2EE approaches.

Comment: Really you need to ask the Spring guys. We can't speak for them with any authority...

Comment: I think this question may belong to Spring forums(not sure though).  Another point - these are only *goals* - I may declare that my goal is become a spaceman, but it does not mean that I am a professional pilot.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov yes, but I ask what does that points means, not if the Spring developer achieved that points

Comment: @TimB please give me a reference to good spring forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through below links to know more :

[spring forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/124744-why-using-spring-instead-of-jee6)

[spring-3-0-vs-java-ee-6-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822812/spring-3-0-vs-java-ee-6-0)

[Spring vs Java EE](http://java.dzone.com/articles/thibaultdelor)

[Why Java EE Lost and Spring Won](http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-java-ee-lost-and-spring)

Comment: thanks but it provide only a partial answer to my 11th question

Comment: A fat downvote for shameless [plagiarism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do) from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234864/spring-advantages-over-current-java-ee).