# how to make choice between spring framework and EJB3

Tags: java, spring, ejb-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JEE6 vs. Spring 3 stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499323/jee6-vs-spring-3-stack)

Let I’m going to develop a mission critical application which will be massively transaction based. I will do it with Java. Now I have to choose the technology. My application must be scalable, good performing, code must be maintainable and I want to get long term ROI. First thing, I’m going to choose framework. As a framework, spring comes at first in my mind. But I know there are more like EJB3 or anything. Now my question, what should I choice, EJB3 with JPA or spring framework with Hibernate. I know every technology have tradeoffs.  Can anyone help me to make good choice? And one thing to make clear, I’m still learner.And I want to know advantage and disadvantage of EJB and spring framework too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I want to know advantage and disadvantage of EJB and spring
>   framework too

Both are light and POJO based, and you could get a good picture from similar threads. You might find that many of the pain-points that existed with EJB 2.x are no longer there.

'EJB' might simplify things for you

- If your application would need distributed transactions started by remote clients
- If your application is message-driven

> Now my question, what should I choice, EJB3 with JPA or spring
>   framework with Hibernate.

Also look at adding CDI to the stack ( i.e EJB3.x + JPA + CDI ) and then compare with (Spring + Hibernate)