# Evaluating differences between EJB Enterprise application and Spring MVC framework?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

Suppose I have to create a shopping cart website, it should accept lot of requests and process their request without any performance issue. Which method I can use EJB Enterprise application or Spring MVC framework..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the two are mutually exclusive. Here is a good discussion on coderanch that really helped me.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/317507/EJB-JEE/java/EJB-MVC-pattern

Hope this helps.

Comment: Guy this thread is 10 years old and is about ejb 2.x at best, things have evolved a lot since this. And no, Spring and Java EE are not intended to be coupled, there are concurrent solution, but you can indeed use both in an application

Answer (score 0):

The well asked question IMHO would be Spring MVC vs JSF as the view part of the Java EE stack is currently JSF.

IMHO both are server centric (pages are built on server side) and quite obsolete now, I would personally go on a server part exposing a rest API consumed by a html5/javascript client.

Both Spring and Java EE stacks are well suited for building rest services (Using Jax-RS for Java EE or [one of theses approaches](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/25/building-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-3-1-and-java-based-configuration-part-2/) for Spring).

I would personally go with the Java EE stack as I prefer by far CDI to spring DI anyway just keep in mind that Java EE is the standard way but spring probably evolve faster.

Have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499323/java-ee-6-vs-spring-3-stack?lq=1) before choosing.